# "Expected type" warning from changing dictionary value from None type to str type within a function (Pycharm IDE)

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a dictionary for which the key `"name"` is initialized to `None` (as this be easily used in `if name:` blocks) if a name is read in it is then assigned to name.

All of this works fine but Pycharm throws a warning when "name" is changed due to the change in type. While this isn't the end of the world it's a pain for debugging (and could be a pain for maintaining the code). Does anyone know if there is a way either to provide something akin to a type hint to the dictionary or failing that to tell Pycharm the change of type is intended?

code replicating issue:

```
from copy import deepcopy

test = {
    "name": None,
    "other_variables": "Something"
}


def read_info():
    test_2 = deepcopy(test)
    test_2["name"] = "this is the name"  # Pycharm shows warning
    return test_2["name"]
```

ideal solution:

```
from copy import deepcopy

test = {
    "name": None type=str,
    "other_variables": "Something"
}


def read_info():
    test_2 = deepcopy(test)
    test_2["name"] = "this is the name"  # no warning
    return test_2["name"]
```

Note:
I know that setting the default value to `""` would behave the same but a) it's handy having it print out "None" if name is printed before assignment and b) I find it slightly more readable to have `None` instead of `""`.

Note_2:
I am unaware why (it may be a bug or intended for some reason I don't understand) but Pycharm only gives a wanrning if the code shown above is found within a function. i.e. replacing the `read_info()` function with the lines:

```
test_2 = deepcopy(test)
test_2["name"] = "this is the name"  # Pycharm shows warning
```

Does not give a warning

Comment: btw, it should be `if name is not None:` (or rather the opposite for your case `if name is None:`) since it's `None`, it's conventional to check the type this way (when using `None`) instead of using boolean logic

Comment: You might be looking for [TypedDict](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/)

Comment: you can't easily annotate type of individual values in a dict (except going to a https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict which makes the dict structure more rigid) ... if all the values are `str` you could annotate the whole dict as `test: dict[str, Optional[str]] = { ... }` to allow some values to be `None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type hinting that dictionary with `dict[str, None | str]` (Python 3.10+, older versions need to use `typing.Dict[str, typing.Optional[str]]`) seems to fix this:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

test: dict[str, None | str] = {
    "name": None,
    "other_variables": "Something"
}


def read_info():
    test_2 = deepcopy(test)
    test_2["name"] = "this is the name"  # no warning
    return test_2["name"]
```

As noticed by @Tomerikoo simply type hinting as `dict` also works (this should work on all? Python versions that support type hints too):

```py
test: dict = {
    "name": None,
    "other_variables": "Something"
}
```

Comment: I think that may be a 3.10 thing as I'm running 3.9 and your code throws an error but I will check out typed dicts, thanks

Comment: Hey can you please explain what does the syntax `dict[str, None | str]` mean?

Comment: oh, I was wondering when those cool type hints were introduced, since I never have used 3.9 (used 3.8 before switching to 3.10)

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi It's a type hint saying the object is a dict, with `str` typed keys, and values that can be either `None` or `str`

Comment: @Matiiss [PEP 604](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-604-new-type-union-operator) was indeed introduced in 3.10

Comment: Interestingly, typing simply as `dict[str, str]` doesn't raise any warnings as well... I'm starting to think this should be a Pycharm issue as I can't see why this would happen in a function but not outside it (the previous example in the question)

Comment: Even more interesting: simply typing as `test: dict` removes the warning...

Comment: yeah, interesting, that works on other versions too, well, now at least there's a specific hint, but I'll add this too to the question